# Javascript - Get a function's name as a string

Tags: javascript

So I am including certain library like this

```
var start = function() { ... }

var loadScript = function() {
    script      = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src  = 'https://whatever.com/js?callback=start';
    document.body.appendChild(script)
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

As you see, I set a function called "start" as callback for the library. The trouble is that if I minify the file, the function isn't called `start` anymore.

I tried this, but it does not work.

```
    script.src  = 'https://whatever.com/js?callback=' + start.name;
```

How can I programatically add the name of the function to the `src` attribute?

**EDIT**

I am using Rails 4, and the assets are in Coffeescript, so I do not think I can use named function declarations.

Comment: Because of the way you're declaring your functions, they really *never* have names. Assigning a function reference to a variable does not give a function a name.

Comment: That said, your minifier should have a way of marking a symbol as being "exported" or something like that. How are you minifying? *edit* - yes true; I was just being needlessly pedantic :)

Comment: Where did you set `start.name`?

Comment: can you show example library code org and min?

Comment: What is your minifier?

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most minifiers won't collapse global pointers. So if you had `window.start` (although not super recommended to have too many generic global names like that).

Or, to justify it, `window.MyAPP.Myutil.start`

Another thing to keep in mind is that anonymous functions don't have `name` properties, even though you've assigned it to a variable. You'll need to add it to the function declaration.

```
window.start = function start() {
  // stuff
}
```

Comment: I am using Rails, and the asset are in Coffeescript, so Im not sure if I can write named function declarations

Comment: If the function has to be used for a JSONP callback, it has to be global anyway.

Comment: @Pointy is right. Which in that case, just make it an actual global by assigning it to the window.

Comment: I understand! I thought it was global, but Coffeescript gave it its own scope. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this and it will work with any minifier.

```
var start = function() { ... }
var someObj = {'start': start};
```

Then Use `someObj['start']()` to call your start function.